# Dynamic struts2 checkbox loading using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, struts2

As per requirement I have to do  dynamic checkbox in struts2 . Like for first action call a checkbox list will appear and selecting on any of the checkbox another set of checkboxes will loaded in the div. I use struts2 iterator to loop through the checkbox and create a dynamic div after each checkbox and call an action through jquery. The action is called and the result is also shown in console but it is not loaded in the div.code is given below
First JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="categoryList" var="eachCheck">
    <s:checkbox name="%{#eachCheck}" id="%{#eachCheck}" cssClass="category_checkbox" labelposition="left"  label="%{#eachCheck}"/> 
    <s:div id="%{#eachCheck}"></s:div>
</s:iterator>
```

Jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.category_checkbox').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked)
    {

        var checkbox_id=$(this).attr("id");
        console.log(checkbox_id);
        var loaded_div="#"+checkbox_id;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url : "loadSubCategory",
            data : "categoryName="+checkbox_id,
            beforeSend:function(){
            },
            success:function(data,textStatus){

               // alert("data "+data);
               // alert("textStatus "+textStatus);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);
                $(loaded_div).html(data);
               // alert("after ");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(exception);
            //  getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
            }
        });
    }


});
});
```

Second JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="subcategoryList" var="eachSub">
    <s:checkbox name="%{#eachSub}" id="%{#eachSub}"  labelposition="left"  label="%{#eachSub}"/> 
    <s:div id="%{#eachSub}"></s:div>
</s:iterator>
```

Action class:

```
public class DiagnosticCentreAction extends ActionSupport {

private List categoryList;
private List subcategoryList;
private String categoryName;

public DiagnosticCentreAction() {
}

public String loadCategory() {
    categoryList=new ArrayList();
    categoryList.add("category1");
    categoryList.add("category2");
    categoryList.add("category3");
    categoryList.add("category4");
    System.out.println("hiiiiii");
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String loadSubCategory(){
     System.out.println("called ");
     subcategoryList=new ArrayList();
     switch (categoryName) {
        case "category1":
            subcategoryList.add("sub1cat1");
            subcategoryList.add("sub2cat1");
            subcategoryList.add("sub3cat1");
            subcategoryList.add("sub4cat1");
            System.out.println("subcategoryList "+subcategoryList);
            break;
        case "category2":
            subcategoryList.add("sub1cat2");
            subcategoryList.add("sub2cat2");
            subcategoryList.add("sub3cat2");
            System.out.println("subcategoryList "+subcategoryList);
            break;
        default:
            subcategoryList.add("sub1cat3");
            System.out.println("subcategoryList "+subcategoryList);
            break;


    }
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `id` must be unique. Don't use `<s:div>`. What happens if someone checks multiple checkboxes?

Comment: id is unique.each list item has become id in the div.

Comment: And in checkbox. So, not unique.

Answer (score 0):

@Aleksandr M is correct.  You have the same "id" on your div and checkbox.  You need to make them different.

```
<s:iterator value="categoryList" var="eachCheck">
  <s:checkbox name="%{#eachCheck}" id="%{#eachCheck}" cssClass="category_checkbox" labelposition="left"  label="%{#eachCheck}"/> 
  <!-- append _div here to make it unique -->
  <s:div id="%{#eachCheck}_div"></s:div>
```

Change the JS to append the _div when looking for the target div

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.category_checkbox').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked)
    {

        var checkbox_id=$(this).attr("id");
        console.log(checkbox_id);
        // append the _div in
        var loaded_div="#"+checkbox_id + "_div";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url : "loadSubCategory",
            data : "categoryName="+checkbox_id,
            beforeSend:function(){
            },
            success:function(data,textStatus){

               // alert("data "+data);
               // alert("textStatus "+textStatus);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);
                $(loaded_div).html(data);
               // alert("after ");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(exception);
            //  getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
            }
        });
    }


});
});
```